# How deep can the axle go in the Powered Up L motor?

Tags: technic, motor, moc, powered-up, control-plus

I am trying to make a MOC but I can't decide how long the axle could be so it can go fully into the motor but not extending out of the other side. Could you tell me how long the axle can go in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is only 1 stud deep.

So an axle of 5L always sticks out 4 studs

Comment: It's worth noting that it's the same thing with almost all motors that dont have double-sided axle holes (example of double sided axle hole is in ev3 large motor.)

Comment: ok SPIKE has 1 stud deep on both (M and L) and the newest motor is 1 stud deep on the top.

Comment: @mindstormsboi My guess is that the reason for this is to prevent anyone sticking a 2L axle all the way in, rendering the motor useless

Comment: Ok I don't have any of these motors.